# Get and Set value assosiated with specified index

Tags: c#, list

I'm creating a list and want to set value of an item added in list and then retrieive that value to display.

```
// Create a list of strings

List<string> AuthorList = new List<string>();

AuthorList.Add("AA");

AuthorList.Add("BB");

AuthorList.Add("CC");

AuthorList.Add("DD");

AuthorList.Add("EE");

// Set Item value

AuthorList["AA"] = 20;

// Get Item value

Int16 age = Convert.ToInt16(AuthorList["AA"]);

// Get first item of a List

string auth = AuthorList[0];

Console.WriteLine(auth);

// Set first item of a List

AuthorList[0] = "New Author";
```

But error occurred

> "best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List.this[int]' has some invalid
>   arguments"

Help me to correct this code.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by the invalid line at all. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you express by assigning a 20 to `AuthorList["AA"]`? Where does the 20 come from?

Answer (score 1):

List of single value if you want to store key pair use [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

```
Dictionary<string,int> AuthorList  = new Dictionary<string,int>();
AuthorList.Add("AA", 20);
AuthorList.Add("BB", 30);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [`Dictionary<string,int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) instead of a `List<string>`.

```
var authorAges = new Dictionary<string,int>();

authorAges.Add("AA",60);
authorAges.Add("BB",61);
authorAges["CC"] = 63; //add or update

// Set Item value
authorAges["AA"] = 20;

// Get Item value
int age = authorAges["AA"];

// Get first item of a List
string auth = authorAges.Keys.First();
Console.WriteLine(auth);

// Set first item of a List 
// (You can't change the key of an existing item, 
//  but you can remove it and add a new item)
var firstKey = authorAges.Keys.First();
authorAges.Remove(firstKey);
authorAges["New author"] = 32;
```

It is worth nothing that there is really no "first" in a dictionary. Maybe you should create an `Author` class and have a list of those:

```
class Author 
{ 
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Age {get; set;}
}
```

Then

```
var authors = new List<Author>();

authors.Add(new Author { Name = "AA" };
authors.Add(new Author { Name = "BB"};

// Get first item of a List
Author firstAuthor = authors[0];
Console.WriteLine(
    "First author -- Name:{0} Age:{1}",firstAuthor.Name, firstAuthor.Age);

// Get Item value
int age = authors[1].Age

// Set first item of a List 
authors[0] = new Author { Name = "New Author"};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use key pair with [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). Try to use [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

> Represents a collection of keys and values.

Try with;

```
Dictionary<string,int> YourAuthorList  = new Dictionary<string,int>();
```

`string` for your `AA`, `BB`, `CC` values, `int` for `20`, `30`, etc. Example;

```
YourAuthorList.Add("AA", 20);
```

Comment: The List class has three properties – Capacity, Count, and Item. And the Item property is used to  get and set the value associated with the specified index. So I want to just set and then get the value.